# I accidentally opened the back of an automatic wind unwind point and shoot camera

Tags: film, 35mm, point-and-shoot

I'm not sure how many shots i have shot about 10 and i dont rememeber if it unwinds or winds after i closed it back. Will my film roll stay on the unexposed or it will go back to the first frame? My cam is Pentax iqzoom 115m same with the other pentax zoom and espios  point and shoot. my film count went back to 1.

Comment: Were you in total darkness when you opened the back? For how long was it open?

Comment: >how many shots are left?

... Really? How can WE tell?

Comment: If you value the few photos that could have survived, send the roll to develop and hope for the best.

Comment: the first few shots are not that important i just shot maybe 5 times? and it went back to 1. i just want to make sure if i can still use the roll of film inside of my point and shoot camera. also it is an automatic point and shoot where it winds and rewinds.

Answer (score 1):

I work in a photo lab and can tell you that you lost approximately 5 frames, the one you were on and 2 on either side. If your film didn't rewind then the rest of the roll that was still stored in the canister should b fine.  Get it developed since most of the roll should turn out.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing from stopping it rewinding, so either it has rewound until the film is in the cartridge (and without the film start, the camera can no longer resume on its own) or it didn't.

So you can just reopen in the dark and check (but wash your hands and dry them well first).  If there is film, taking 3 shots in the dark (and "dark" means dark, like leaving the lens cap on) should get you to a good piece of the negative.  If there isn't, without a film start retriever or opening and fiddling with the cartridge in a darkroom (and it has to be completely dark, no emergency light), you won't get anything useful done with the film.  And you would need to know how many shots to take before getting to a free part.  It would not make a whole lot of sense to take all that risk, for both the sake of photos you already shot and that you are going to shoot afterwards.

Comment: the first few shots are not that important i just shot maybe 5 times? and it went back to 1. i just want to make sure if i can still use the roll of film inside of my point and shoot camera. also it is an automatic point and shoot where it winds and rewinds

Comment: @Jefferson. What  he/she meant was to open the back of the camera in complete darkness and feel for the film. If it's not there, then it has be wound back into the film canister and your easiest option is to just process it. If the film is there, then you will have exposed that part of the film and a couple of exposures either side when you opened it, so take 3 photos in the complete darkness, which will wind the film to a point that probably wasn't affected by you opening the back. It's unlikely that the camera wound the film back to the start (exposure 1).